# background-image issue on iphone 4

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, background-image

I have really wield problem that i couldn't solve and didn't find any explanation.

this is the site i'm changing (v2) : [http://patrolmanp.com/v2/](http://patrolmanp.com/v2/?v2)

on iphone4, the credits section is not stretching all over its content
but on other devices, like 4s\5\5s, its working find

**iPhone 4** - 
[image]

**iPhone 4s** (and everything else looks like this) - 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1120, user-scalable=yes">
```

To

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">
```